# Resolve aggregate and Non-aggregate mix error for IF results in Tableau

Tags: if-statement, error-handling, aggregate-functions, tableau-api

I am trying to do the following in Tableau.

If the chosen key figure is sales or volume (non-aggregate fields) then call calculation1 else calculation 2.

```
IF ATTR([Choose Key Figure])= "Sales"
THEN [Periodic Calculation]
ELSEIF ATTR([Choose Key Figure])= "Volume"
THEN [Periodic Calculation]
ELSEIF ATTR([Choose Key Figure])="profit"
THEN [Periodic Calculation 2]
ELSEIF ATTR([Choose Key Figure])="price per unit"
THEN [Periodic Calculation 2]
END
```

But I am getting the following error:
"Cannot mix aggregate and non-aggregate comparisons or results in 'IF' expressions."

Periodic Calculation

```
IF [Choose Vol/NNS]="NNS"
AND [Choose Period]=-1
AND DATEDIFF("month",[Dates], [Choose Current Month])<2
AND
DATEDIFF("month",[Dates],[Choose Current Month] )>0
then [(Actuals+Planned) NNS]
ELSEIF [Choose Vol/NNS]="Volume"
AND    [Choose Period]=-1
AND DATEDIFF("month",[Dates], [Choose Current Month])<2
AND
DATEDIFF("month",[Dates],[Choose Current Month] )>0
THEN [(Actuals + Planned) Volume]
ELSEIF [Choose Vol/NNS]="NNS"
AND [Choose Period]=-3
AND DATEDIFF("month",[Dates], [Choose Current Month])<4
AND
DATEDIFF("month",[Dates],[Choose Current Month] )>0
then [(Actuals+Planned) NNS]
ELSEIF [Choose Vol/NNS]="Volume"
AND [Choose Period]=-3
AND DATEDIFF("month",[Dates], [Choose Current Month])<4
AND
DATEDIFF("month",[Dates],[Choose Current Month] )>0
THEN [(Actuals + Planned) Volume]
ELSEIF [Choose Vol/NNS]="NNS"
AND [Choose Period]=-6
AND DATEDIFF("month",[Dates], [Choose Current Month])<7
AND
DATEDIFF("month",[Dates],[Choose Current Month] )>0
then [(Actuals+Planned) NNS]
ELSEIF [Choose Vol/NNS]="Volume"
AND     [Choose Period]=-6
AND DATEDIFF("month",[Dates], [Choose Current Month])<7
AND
DATEDIFF("month",[Dates],[Choose Current Month] )>0
THEN [(Actuals + Planned) Volume]
ELSEIF [Choose Vol/NNS]="NNS"
AND     [Choose Period]=1
AND DATEDIFF("month",[Dates], [Choose Current Month])<0
AND
DATEDIFF("month",[Dates],[Choose Current Month] )>-2
THEN [(Actuals+Planned) NNS]
ELSEIF [Choose Vol/NNS]="Volume"
AND     [Choose Period]=1
AND DATEDIFF("month",[Dates], [Choose Current Month])<0
AND
DATEDIFF("month",[Dates],[Choose Current Month] )>-2
THEN [(Actuals + Planned) Volume]
ELSEIF [Choose Vol/NNS]="NNS"
AND     [Choose Period]=3
AND DATEDIFF("month",[Dates], [Choose Current Month])<0
AND
DATEDIFF("month",[Dates],[Choose Current Month] )>-4
THEN [(Actuals+Planned) NNS]
ELSEIF [Choose Vol/NNS]="Volume"
AND     [Choose Period]=3
AND DATEDIFF("month",[Dates], [Choose Current Month])<0
AND
DATEDIFF("month",[Dates],[Choose Current Month] )>-4
THEN [(Actuals + Planned) Volume]
ELSEIF [Choose Vol/NNS]="NNS"
AND     [Choose Period]=6
AND DATEDIFF("month",[Dates], [Choose Current Month])<0
AND
DATEDIFF("month",[Dates],[Choose Current Month] )>-7
THEN [(Actuals+Planned) NNS]
ELSEIF [Choose Vol/NNS]="Volume"
AND     [Choose Period]=6
AND DATEDIFF("month",[Dates], [Choose Current Month])<0
AND
DATEDIFF("month",[Dates],[Choose Current Month] )>-7
THEN [(Actuals + Planned) Volume]
```

END

Periodic Calculation 2

```
IF [Choose IGM$/NNSP]="NNSP"
AND [Choose Period]=-1
AND ATTR(DATEDIFF("month",[Dates], [Choose Current Month]))<2
and ATTR(DATEDIFF("month",[Dates],[Choose Current Month] ))>0
THEN [(Actuals + Planned) NNSP]
ELSEIF [Choose IGM$/NNSP]="IGM$"
AND [Choose Period]=-1
AND ATTR(DATEDIFF("month",[Dates], [Choose Current Month]))<2
and ATTR(DATEDIFF("month",[Dates],[Choose Current Month] ))>0
THEN [(Actuals + Planned) IGM$]
ELSEIF [Choose IGM$/NNSP]="NNSP"
AND [Choose Period]=-3
AND ATTR(DATEDIFF("month",[Dates], [Choose Current Month]))<4
and ATTR(DATEDIFF("month",[Dates],[Choose Current Month] ))>0
THEN [(Actuals + Planned) NNSP]
ELSEIF [Choose IGM$/NNSP]="IGM$"
AND [Choose Period]=-3
AND ATTR(DATEDIFF("month",[Dates], [Choose Current Month]))<4
and ATTR(DATEDIFF("month",[Dates],[Choose Current Month] ))>0
THEN [(Actuals + Planned) IGM$]
ELSEIF [Choose IGM$/NNSP]="NNSP"
AND [Choose Period]=-6
AND ATTR(DATEDIFF("month",[Dates], [Choose Current Month]))<7
and ATTR(DATEDIFF("month",[Dates],[Choose Current Month] ))>0
THEN [(Actuals + Planned) NNSP]
ELSEIF [Choose IGM$/NNSP]="IGM$"
AND [Choose Period]=-6
AND ATTR(DATEDIFF("month",[Dates], [Choose Current Month]))<7
and ATTR(DATEDIFF("month",[Dates],[Choose Current Month] ))>0
THEN [(Actuals + Planned) IGM$]
ELSEIF [Choose IGM$/NNSP]="NNSP"
AND [Choose Period]=1
AND ATTR(DATEDIFF("month",[Dates], [Choose Current Month]))<0
and ATTR(DATEDIFF("month",[Dates],[Choose Current Month] ))>-2
THEN [(Actuals + Planned) NNSP]
ELSEIF [Choose IGM$/NNSP]="IGM$"
AND [Choose Period]=1
AND ATTR(DATEDIFF("month",[Dates], [Choose Current Month]))<0
and ATTR(DATEDIFF("month",[Dates],[Choose Current Month] ))>-2
THEN [(Actuals + Planned) IGM$]
ELSEIF [Choose IGM$/NNSP]="NNSP"
AND [Choose Period]=3
AND ATTR(DATEDIFF("month",[Dates], [Choose Current Month]))<0
and ATTR(DATEDIFF("month",[Dates],[Choose Current Month] ))>-4
THEN [(Actuals + Planned) NNSP]
ELSEIF [Choose IGM$/NNSP]="IGM$"
AND [Choose Period]=3
AND ATTR(DATEDIFF("month",[Dates], [Choose Current Month]))<0
and ATTR(DATEDIFF("month",[Dates],[Choose Current Month] ))>-4
THEN [(Actuals + Planned) IGM$]
ELSEIF [Choose IGM$/NNSP]="NNSP"
AND [Choose Period]=6
AND ATTR(DATEDIFF("month",[Dates], [Choose Current Month]))<0
and ATTR(DATEDIFF("month",[Dates],[Choose Current Month] ))>-7
THEN [(Actuals + Planned) NNSP]
ELSEIF [Choose IGM$/NNSP]="IGM$"
AND [Choose Period]=6
AND ATTR(DATEDIFF("month",[Dates], [Choose Current Month]))<0
and ATTR(DATEDIFF("month",[Dates],[Choose Current Month] ))>-7
THEN [(Actuals + Planned) IGM$]
END
```

Can anyone help with how to work around this error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If [Choose Key Figure] is a parameter, and [Periodic Calculation] and [Periodic Calculation 2] are row level (non aggregate) calculations, then you can either:

1. remove all the calls to ATTR() in your calculated field
   or
2. remove all the calls to ATTR() and invoke an aggregation function such as SUM() on each reference to [Periodic Calculation] or [Periodic Calculation 2]
   or
3. keep the calls to ATTR() and invoke an aggregation function such as SUM() on each reference to [Periodic Calculation] or [Periodic Calculation 2]

The difference between 1 and 2 is whether to specify the aggregation function for your calculated field inside the calculation or in the Tableau workbook shelves where it is used.

No real reason to choose the third approach in this case since parameters can only have a single value at a time, so the ATTR() call is not useful.