# Identify Open and close count week wise based on Open and Close date in each row

Tags: charts, data-visualization, tableau-api, reporting, business-intelligence

I have ID, open date, close date and current status( either open or close) in my data set. 
How can i see total new open each week ,total close each week, total carry over from previous weeks .So on X Axis I should get week interval dates and 3 different color graphs ( One for new open each week , one for close per week , one for carry over from all previous weeks).
This needs to be done in tableau.

I have tried creating two calculated field as below:
OpenEachWeek: {Fixed DATETRUNC('week', [Open Date]): Count(ID)}
CloseEachWeek:{Fixed DATETRUNC('week', [CloseDate]): Count(ID)}

But I can use only one date on X-Axis so if I use Open Date, Open count works properly but close count shows wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I would try creating a few IF statements in calculated fields to accomplish this. 
For example, new open each week:

```
if open date > (datetrunc('week',(today()) then 1 else 0 end
```

For a carryover from previous week I would just make bookends.

```
if open date > (datetrunc('week',today()) 
and open date < (datetrunc('week',(dateadd('day', -14, today())
then 1 else 0 end
```

Then try doing a count of this value as the discrete measure in your row should count the total that meet this criteria.

If you get a aggregate/non aggregate mix check this out (just a wrap of `attr()`).

[Resolve aggregate and Non-aggregate mix error for IF results in Tableau](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32805142/resolve-aggregate-and-non-aggregate-mix-error-for-if-results-in-tableau)